# Error occurs on custom inquiry screen related to view BQL

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom inquiry screen with one filter field at the top.  This works as expected.

Among the grid data, there are also two fields included which are NOT tied to the database, and are types [PXInt] and [PXString].  The current (working) filter BQL uses one of the fields that IS tied to the database as follows:

```
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXSelectReadonly<xTACTodoDetail,
           Where<Current<ToDoFilter.employeeID>, IsNull,
           Or<xTACTodoDetail.assignTo, Equal<Current<ToDoFilter.employeeID>>>>> TodoDetail;
```

As I said, this works as expected. 
Now I've added a field to the screen filter and to the BQL as follows:

Field:

```
    #region BusAcct
    public abstract class busAcct : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXString(30, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Bus. Acct.")]
    [PXDimensionSelector("BIZACCT", typeof(BAccount.acctCD),typeof(BAccount.acctCD), DescriptionField = typeof(BAccount.acctName))]
    public virtual string BusAcct { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

BQL:

```
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXSelectReadonly<xTACTodoDetail,
            Where2<Where<Current<ToDoFilter.employeeID>, IsNull,
                   Or<xTACTodoDetail.assignTo, Equal<Current<ToDoFilter.employeeID>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<ToDoFilter.busAcct>, IsNull,
                Or<xTACTodoDetail.busAcct, Equal<Current<ToDoFilter.busAcct>>>>>>> TodoDetail;
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

The field in the inquiry screen's DAC is not tied to the database, and is populated using the xTACToDoDetail_RowSelecting event (this is because depending on several factors, it will obtain the Business Account from different DACs, so conditional logic is needed.   Could this be why I'm getting the error?  Everything compiles fine.

Comment: Turn on Request Profiler and check the SQL query and add to the question.

Comment: you cannot query an unbound field if that is what you are trying to do? If so the SQL that is being generated is going to leave out the field name and that could result in something like "WHERE = 'x'" as the field doesn't exist in the database.